# Behavior of Redux Reducer when Multiple Action is Called within A Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have recently learned the MERN stack and is currently making a side project using it. I am stumbling into a problem in which my Redux Reducer is overriding each other everytime a different action is called. Here is the complete and detailed problem.

Questions:

1. Behaviour of invoking actions on a React Component. Let's say that we have decided to create an action and implement it in one of our React Component, we have done all of the setup (e.g. creating reducer and updating the state, creating the action itself and connecting it to the react component using `connect` from `react-redux`). I was just wondering when I call multiple actions in our React Component from `componentDidMount`, why does the state override each other. E.g.

```js
componentDidMount(){
  // Action updates 'user: {}' state in our reducer
  this.props.fetchUserData();
  // Action updates 'clients:{}' state 
  this.props.fetchClientsData();
}
```

Resulting State from Reducers:

```js
user: {}, // Overrided by the fetchClientsData()
clients { clientsData }
```

Aren't we essentially update the specific reducer state (fetchUserData() updates 'user:{}' and fetchClientsData() updates 'clients: {}'). WHY IS IT OVERRIDING? I have checked my Redux Devtools middleware and It is infact overriding. HOW DO I NOT OVERRIDE THE OTHER STATE IN THE REDUCER? Thank you!

Update: 
- Here is my reducers:
Index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";
import NotificationReducer from "./NotificationReducer";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";
import DataReducer from "./DataReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    auth: AuthReducer,
    notification: NotificationReducer,
    data: DataReducer,
});
```

AuthReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_USER, FETCH_HOSPITAL } from "../actionTypes";

export default (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload || false;
        case FETCH_HOSPITAL:
            return action.payload || false;
        default:
            return false;
    }
};
```

DataReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from "../actionTypes";

export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return { ...state, data: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I couldn't encapsulate the 'componentDidMount...' with code block for some reason.

Comment: Can you share your reducer?

Comment: @IoannisPotouridis I have attached my reducer in the post above. Hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't available earlier, I'm glad a solution was posted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in your `AuthReducer`, whatever you return from these `switch case` statement becomes your new state.

The same way you are doing in your `DataReducer.js` file

Therefore you have to update your state like:

```
export default (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_USER:
          return {...state, users: action.payload || false};
      case FETCH_HOSPITAL:
          return {...state, clients: action.payload || false};
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
```

Also it would be a good thing if you would initialize your state

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Much appreciated

Comment: glad could help :)